# Html Agility Pack nextsibling not finding element if there are white spaces between tags

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to find the nextSibling innerText of a specific tag, but I can't get the proper value when I try to parse an html string which contains white spaces or new lines

here is my code:

```
private string getTableTdValue()
{
    /*If I strip all white space between tag I get proper results
    string myHtml =
        "<td align='right' width='186'>Text1</td><td align='center' width='51'>Here the result I want to get</td><td width='186'>Text2</td>";*/

    string myHtml =
        @"
        <td align='right' width='186'>Text1</td>
        <td align='center' width='51'>Here the result I want to get</td>
        <td width='186'>Text2</td>";

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    HtmlNodeCollection cols = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@width='186']");

    var tdValue = string.Empty;
    foreach (HtmlNode col in cols)
    {
        if (col.InnerText == "Text1")
        {
            tdValue = col.NextSibling.InnerText;            
        }
    }

    return tdValue;

}
```

Can I get nextSibling value whithout requiring to remove all whitespaces between tags?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HtmlAgilityPack NextSibling.InnerText value is blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535284/htmlagilitypack-nextsibling-innertext-value-is-blank)