# Select node based on sibling properties - HtmlAgilityPack - C#

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML-document that is structured as follows

```
<ul class="beverageFacts">
<li>
    <span>Vintage</span> 
    <strong>2007&nbsp;</strong>
</li>
<li>
    <span>ABV</span> 
    <strong>13,0&nbsp;%</strong>
</li>
<li>
    <span>Sugar</span> 
    <strong>5&nbsp;gram/liter</strong>
</li>
```

I need to parse the values of the `<strong>`-tags to corresponding `string`'s, depending on what value the `<span>`-tag has.

I have the following:

```
String vintage;
String sugar;
String abv;
```

As of now, I am looping through each child node of the `beverageFacts`-node checking the values to parse it to the correct corresponding `string`.
The code I have so far to get the "Vintage"-value is the following, though the result is always `null`.

```
HtmlNodeCollection childNodes = bevFactNode.ChildNodes;
foreach (HtmlNode subNode in childNodes)
{
    if (subNode.InnerText.TrimStart() == "Vintage")
        vintage = subNode.NextSibling.InnerText.Trim();
}
```

I believe my selection of the nodes is incorrect, but I cannot figure out how to properly do it in the most efficient way.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

---

**Edit 2013-07-29**

I have tried to remove the whitespaces as suggested by [enricoariel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1037814/enricoariel) in the comments using the following code

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument page = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.systembolaget.se/" + articleID);

        string cleanDoc = Regex.Replace(page.DocumentNode.OuterHtml, @"\s*(?<capture><(?<markUp>\w+)>.*<\/\k<markUp>>)\s*", "${capture}", RegexOptions.Singleline);

        HtmlDocument cleanPage = new HtmlDocument();
        cleanPage.LoadHtml(cleanDoc);
```

The resulting is still

```
 String vintage = null;
```

Comment: The problem is that the nextSibling is a white space. if you strip all white space between tags you get proper results. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785682/html-agility-pack-nextsibling-not-finding-element-if-there-are-white-spaces-betw

Comment: I do not see how your question really helps me out here. If the sibling was a whitespace, wouldn't my vintage-string then be set to "" instead of null aswell?

Comment: remove white spaces and you see it will work:
<ul class="beverageFacts"><li><span>Vintage</span><strong>2007&nbsp;</strong></li>...

Comment: Got it working now! You are correct that there are whitespaces, and my method of cleaning it doesn't work! I will post an answer that displays my solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the HTML markup, I realized I didn't go deep enough in the nodes.
Also, as enricoariel pointed out, there are whitespaces that I do not clean properly. By skipping the sibling which is the whitespaces, and instead jump to the following, I get the correct result.

```
        foreach (HtmlNode bevFactNode in bevFactsNodes)
        {
            HtmlNodeCollection childNodes = bevFactNode.ChildNodes;
            foreach (HtmlNode node in childNodes)
            {
                foreach(HtmlNode subNode in node.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (subNode.InnerText.Trim() == "Årgång")
                        vintage = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(subNode.NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText.Trim());
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Vintage: " + vintage);
```

will output

```
Vintage: 2007
```

---

I decoded the HTML to get the result formatted correctly.

Lessons learned!

Answer (score 0):

to summarize I think the best solution would be stripping all white spaces using a regex prior to retrieve the nextSibling value:

```
    string myHtml =
    @"
    <ul class='beverageFacts'>
    <li>
        <span>Vintage</span> 
        <strong>2007&nbsp;</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>ABV</span> 
        <strong>13,0&nbsp;%</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Sugar</span> 
        <strong>5&nbsp;gram/liter</strong>
    </li>";
    //Remove space after and before tag
myHtml = Regex.Replace(myHtml, @"\s+<", "<", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
myHtml = Regex.Replace(myHtml, @">\s+", "> ", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(myHtml.Replace("/r", "").Replace("/n", "").Replace("/r/n", "").Replace("  ", ""));
doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

HtmlNodeCollection vals = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='beverageFacts']//span");

var myNodeContent = string.Empty;
foreach (HtmlNode val in vals)
{
    if (val.InnerText == "Vintage")
    {
        myNodeContent = val.NextSibling.InnerText;
    }
}

return myNodeContent;
```