# HtmlAgilityPack NextSibling.InnerText value is blank

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack, siblings

I am scraping some data using HtmlAgilityPack.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="id-here">
  <dl>
    <dt> Field Name </dt>
    <dd> Value for above field name </dd>
    <dt> Field Name </dt>
    <dd> Value for above field name </dd>
    <dt> Field Name </dt>
    <dd> Value for above field name </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Now the problem I have is that there is not always a set number of fields so I cant reliably access each of them like:

```
//*[@id="id-here"]/dl[1]/dd[1]
```

as dd[1] may be a name on one page and a telephone on another where the user failed to fill out a name so field is hidden.

so I grab all the DT and DD nodes like so:

```
//*[@id="id-here"]/dl[1]/dt | //*[@id="id-here"]/dl[1]/dd
```

Now I check each node to see if it matches field I want and take the NextSibling value like so:

```
    foreach (HtmlNode node in details)
    {
        if (node.InnerText.Contains("Tel:")) telephone = node.NextSibling.InnerText;
        if (node.InnerText.Contains("Email:")) email = node.NextSibling.InnerText;
    }
```

This works fine for telephone but for some reason when the "Email:" node comes up, both `NextSibling.InnerHTML` & `NextSibling.InnerText` are blank although the next sibling definitely has the data.  If I actually go to that `node` in `details` and look at it the `InnerHTML` is the entire formatted link and the `InnerText` is the email address.

Is the `NextSibling.InnerText` not working because the A tag is making it a child or something?  I have had a look in debugger and just cant find the information I need under `NextSibling`.

I am sure answer is ridiculously simple, I just cant figure it out.  Anyone put me out of my misery?

Comment: Somewhat separate question, but why are you selecting the `dd` elements if you don't actually plan use the selected `dd`s as you iterate through `details`?

Comment: So that I can select the nextSibling.  If I don't select the DD then they wont be there to be the nextSibling.

Comment: The contents of `details` have no bearing on what a node's siblings are, and that is precisely what you are witnessing here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that if `node` is a `dt` element that is separated from its corresponding `dd` element by some whitespace, then `node.NextSibling` is an all-whitespace text node (the space between the `</dt>` and the `<dd>`). If you look at it in the debugger, you will see that `node.NextSibling`'s `NodeType` is `HtmlNodeType.Text` and not `HtmlNodeType.Element`.

I suggest creating a convenience method to get the text of a `dt` node's corresponding `dd`:

```
internal static string GetMatchingDdValue(HtmlNode dtNode)
{
    var found = dtNode.SelectSingleNode("following-sibling::*[1][self::dd]");
    return found == null ? "" : found.InnerText;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
if (node.InnerText.Contains("Tel:")) { telephone = GetMatchingDdValue(node); }
```

---

Here's a breakdown of the somewhat tricky XPath used in my method above:

```
(a) following-sibling::*
```

^ Select all elements that share the same
                               parent as the current node and occur after it.

```
(b) following-sibling::*[1]
```

^ Select the first node in set (a) 
                                  (if there are any)

```
(c) following-sibling::*[1][self::dd]
```

^ Select all nodes in set (b) that
                                            are elements with the name "dd"

`SelectSingleNode()` selects the first node in set (c), which should always either be 1 or 0 nodes.

You could most likely get by with just `following-sibling::dd` or `following-sibling::*`, but the above path contains safeguards. For example, if for some reason, you had the following XML and your current node was the `Tel:` element:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Tel:</dt>
  <dt>Address:</dt>
  <dd>50 Fake St.</dd>
</dl>
```

`following-sibling::dd` would give you the result "50 Fake St.", while `following-sibling::*` would give you the result "Address:". Instead, `following-sibling::*[1][self::dd]` would select an empty nodeset in this case, so the method would correctly produce an empty string as the result.

Comment: Gah, beat me to the punch by 5 sec :) (And with code!)

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly.  What confused me was when I opened up `details` in debugger and saw that say "Email:" was at [0] and then the email address was at [1] so I thought NextSibling would get that next entry.

I am new to xpath and dont fully understand how your xpath works,  I have tried to work it out from reference but not fully understanding it.  I guess I need to get a book on it.

Comment: following-siblings = take all html after this node
* = take any html.  [1] = ??  [self::dd] = selects current node and selects dd? code still works if I remove this bit

Comment: @Guerrilla Added a deconstruction above.

Comment: @JLRishe thank you! I really appreciate you taking the time to explain that to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = @"
<div id='id-here'>
  <dl>
    <dt> Field Name </dt>
    <dd> Value for above field name </dd>
    <dt> Field Name </dt>
    <dd> Value for above field name </dd>
    <dt> Field Name </dt>
    <dd> Value for above field name </dd>
  </dl>
</div>";
html = new Regex(">\r\n\\s*<").Replace(html,"><");
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
Console.Write(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dt")[0].NextSibling.OuterHtml);

<dd> Value for above field name </dd>
```